# Find all holomorphic functions that satisfy a given condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find all holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z^2)=(f(z))^2$.
I'm familiar with the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I'm stuck with this problem. Any hints?

Comment: You could just look what that identity implies for the Taylor series.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ then it has a Taylor expansion which converges everywhere. Suppose
$$
f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i z^i\Longrightarrow (f(z))^2=
\sum_{i,j=0}^\infty a_ia_j z^{i+j}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k}a_{n-k}
$$
On the other hand
$
f(z^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2n}
$. Compare the two to find
$$
\begin{cases}
a_\ell = \sum_{k=0}^{2\ell}a_{k}a_{2\ell-k}&(1)\\
\sum_{k=0}^{2\ell+1}a_{k}a_{2\ell-k+1}=0&(2)
\end{cases}
$$
Let's find the first few $a_n$'s. First of all (by (1) $\ell=0$) $a_0^2=a_0$ Hence either $a_0 = 0$ or $a_0=1$. Let's assume $a_0=1$ for now. Then we find by (2) ($\ell=0$) $2a_0a_1 = 0$ meaning $a_1=0$.

In fact I prove by induction that if $a_0=1$, then for all $i\geq 0$ we have $a_i=0$. Assume we know this for $i<n$ and we want to prove it for $n$. If $n$ is even $=2\ell$, use (1): Left hands side is zero and right hand side is $a_{2\ell}a_0=0$ So $a_{2\ell}=0$. If $n=2\ell+1$ is odd, then use equation (2) to find $a_{2\ell+1}a_0 = 0$, so $a_{2\ell+1}=0$. So

> The only holomorphic function satisfying $(f(z))^2=f(z^2)$ such that $f(0)\neq 0$ ($a_0\neq 0$) is $f(z) = 1$.

Now if $a_0 = 0$. We have $f(z) = zf_1(z)$ where $g(z)$ is another holomorphic function such that $(f_1(z))^2 = f_1(z^2)$. So either $f_1(z)=1$ or $f_1(z)=zf_2(z)$. Going like this you will find that all holomorphic functions of interest are exactly $f(z) = z^m$ for some $m$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $f^{(k)}(0) \neq 0$. (If there is no such integer, then $f \equiv 0$.) Then $f(z)=z^k g(z)$, $g$ an analytic function, $g(0) \neq 0$. We have
$$ g(z^2) = f(z^2)/z^{2k} = f(z)^2/z^{2k} = (f(z)/z^k)^2 = g(z)^2, $$
so $g$ satisfies the same functional equation as $f$. Also, $g(0^2)=g(0)^2$, and $g(0) \neq 0$, so $g(0)=1$. We now prove that $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for any $n>0$.

Suppose that $n$ is the smallest integer greater than $0$ such that $g^{(n)}(0) = a \neq 0$. Then $g(z) = 1 + az^n + o(z^n)$, so
$$ 0 = g(z)^2-g(z^2) = (1+az^n +o(z^n) )^2 -(1+az^{2n}+o(z^{2n})) = 1-1 + 2az^n +(a^2-a) z^{2n} + o(z^{2n}). $$
But it follows, equating coefficients on $z^n$ (or taking $n$ derivatives of both sides, if you prefer), that $a=0$. Hence $g^{(n)}(0)=0$, contradicting that $n$ is the smallest. Hence there is no smallest $n$ and so $g^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n$. It follows that $g$ is constant.